# How can I retrieve #pragma comment data at run time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, comments, pragma

I came across a section on MSDN this evening talking about `#pragma` options. Specifically, the [`#pragma comment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) definition.

Is it possible to pull that information back out at run time (to identify which machine some source code was generated on for example)? If so, how?

For example, how could I retrieve the compile date if I were to add the following `#pragma`:

```
pragma comment( user, "Compiled on " __DATE__ " at " __TIME__ )
```

Comment: @ildjarn: You didn't read enough of the documentation, Seva was correct about `#pragma comment`.

Comment: @Ben : That statement contradicts your own answer, unless I'm misunderstanding the meaning of "*the linker does not process the comment record*".

Comment: @ildjarn: Which version of my answer are you looking at?

Comment: Not really, @Ben. Seva's answer correctly said the comments aren't available, but incorrectly explained why. They're not unavailable because the compiler strips them. They're unavailable because the linker strips them. Furthermore, Seva's answer made it sound like no `#pragma` would ever generate information usable at run time because all `#` generate no code.

Comment: @Rob: I agree that he made an overly broad statement.  But he's correct that `#pragma comment` is stripped by the toolchain (likely an unfortunately non-pendantic use of "compiler").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string "Compiled on " ... is actually in the binary, but it's not directly accessible. What you need to do is actually scan the executable image to find that string. This brings its own set of problems (i.e. how do you find the needle that is your string in the haystack that is the code) without some "marker" to tell you "aha! here it is!"

Why not do something like this to make your life easier?

```
static const char *sCompileInfo = "Compiled on " __DATE__ " at " __TIME__
```

Comment: Yup, fair point - just saw it in passing and wondered if it was another easily available metric. I've been doing a load of stuff with traceability at work recently and would welcome more ways to identify what was compiled where and the like. static const char with the same information is more useful if the program runs, but being able to retrieve information from executables, libs and .dlls without running any code can also be helpful in some circumstances..

Comment: @Jon: Then maybe you want a VERSIONINFO resource?

Comment: @Ben that looks like could be very useful indeed :-)

Comment: @JonCage even if you do the 'static const char *' I showed above, you can still retrieve the information trivially and without loading and/or running any code, using any tool that can scan for strings (e.g. the aptly named 'strings') against the binary.

Answer (score 3):

According to the MSDN page you cited, the content of `#pragma comment` ends up in the linked binary only when the *comment-type* is `exestr`.  Your example is of type `user`, and the documentation very clearly says it won't be linked.  Furthermore, even type `exestr` is no longer processed (again, the documentation calls this out).

---

For a comment stored in the binary file that can be retrieved later without executing the program, try embedding a VERSIONINFO resource into the executable with rc.exe, and reading it with the [`GetFileVersionInfoEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  STRINGTABLE resource types could also be effective.